# What does "18 hours out, destination unknown, a military secret" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

18 hours out, destination unknown, a military secret.

The above is a line from a documentary.
I think this is related to some military because the screen shown in which this line is spoken has fighter airplanes flying and the next is about a military operation.

But still I don't get what this means and who speaks this(sounds like an announcer).
Please inform me about it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

"18 hours out" is military slang for "18 hours away."

i.e. the phrase means "We are 18 hours away from an unknown destination, which is a military secret"

Comment: Isn't "to" instead of "from"?

Comment: @LPH "18 hours away to an unknown destination" doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: It seems that this sounds like the description of a mission, a secret mission, and that what is not known is where it takes place and that the place they are away from is wellknown to them.

Comment: Whether they're going toward or away from it is unclear, either way they are 18 hours away from it. Because English is weird!

Comment: Yes, *18 hours out* means *18 hours before arrival*, or *you are 18 hours **from** your **destination**.* This is heard very often in dialogue like this: "We have an emergency here! How soon can you get here?" "Hang on, we're only an hour out." I associate it with something a navigator (such as a pilot) would say. In short *out* means *away*. Annoyingly, I could find no quick reference to it. Aside from [this protein drink for show animals](https://winwithgolddust.com/products/3-hours-out), which, humorously, demonstrates the same meaning …

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm sure I've heard `out of` used to mean the opposite e.g. "18 hours out of Camp Bastion"

Comment: @JeffUK Yes, *out* ***of***. Using the preposition reverses the meaning, as well as changing the syntax that's used. You are either just *18 hours out* or you are *18 hours out **of** somewhere*.